# error jquery Autocomplete suggestions is undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using `jquery aucomplete` from
https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/
But it works fine for `local` and creates problem when using `server side script`

**Error img**

[image]

My **code** is like

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete"/>
</div>
<div id="selection"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.autocomplete-suggestions { border: 1px solid #999; background: #FFF; cursor: default; overflow: auto; }
.autocomplete-suggestion { padding: 2px 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
.autocomplete-selected { background: #F0F0F0; }
.autocomplete-suggestions strong { font-weight: normal; color: #3399FF; }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<!-- Above js file can be downloaded from
https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js
-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'search.php',
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**PHP Page SCRIPT** **search.php**

```
<?php
    if($_REQUEST['query']=='a')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('AD'=>'Adrew','AU'=>'Australia'));
    }
    if($_REQUEST['query']=='b')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('BR'=>'Brazil','BA'=>'Bangladesh'));
    }
    if($_REQUEST['query']=='i')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('IN'=>'India','IND'=>'Indonasia'));
    }
    return;
?>
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435433/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json ?

Comment: as its work fine on local and not working on live menas there will be some issue for connectivity. you can add firebug plugin to firefox and debug what exactly happening, which error it is giving while sending auto-complete request. may be there is some script files are missing which you have used on local but not added on live server.

Comment: are the html and ´search.php´ on the same server? Otherwise it might have to do with Cross-origin resource sharing

Comment: have u checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713642/undefined-results-in-jquery-autocomplete

Comment: @GaneshBora that was `jquery ui` and I am not using it. See my question and the link which I have given in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the problem

1. First, it gives error for `suggestions.length`
2. Second it was giving problem with `suggestion.value`.

So the below `json encoding` works fine

```
echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array(array('data'=>'AU','value'=>'Australia'),array('data'=>'IN','value'=>'India'))));
```

**Full PHP code**

```
<?php
    if($_REQUEST['query']=='a')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array(array('data'=>'AU','value'=>'Australia'),array('data'=>'IN','value'=>'India'))));
    }
    else if($_REQUEST['query']=='b')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array(array('data'=>'BR','value'=>'Brazil'),array('data'=>'BA','value'=>'Bangladesh'))));
    }
    else if($_REQUEST['query']=='i')
    {
        echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array(array('data'=>'IN','value'=>'India'),array('data'=>'IND','value'=>'Indonesia'))));
    }
    else
        echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array(array('data'=>'NF','value'=>'Not Found'))));
    return;
?>
```

Thanks for all whow were given their precious time
Thanks once again.

Comment: Thank you, for me, I forgot to assign the result to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing the wrong format in PHP, the auto complete needs to receive and array of objects with a `value` property or `label` property or both.

You could do something like this

```
echo json_encode(array('value' => 'AU', 'label' => 'Australia'));
```

Comment: It doesn't need to receive a `value` property or `label` property - you can send back whatever `key(s)` you like

Comment: You're right but then you have to process the response on client side, with these you have a ready list to be displayed.

Comment: Its not working but when I used `echo json_encode(array('suggestions'=>array('suggestion'=>array('value' => 'AU', 'label' => 'Australia'))));`
 It works but now the problem is how can I add more country names in it?